# SSRS SMTP setting on home computer

Tags: reporting-services, smtp

I'm trying to set up a development SSRS server on my home computer, using SQL/SSRS 2019.  I'm having trouble with the SMTP settings for using my gmail account, the email subscription keeps failing with "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

I have successfully set up sendmail tasks on my home computer SSIS with the gmail smtp server, using a C# script and entering the SMTP port #587 and other details but the SSRS config set up doesn't have fields for all that.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I've never tried this but maybe you can add the port to the end of the address e.g. `smtp.gmail.com:578`

Comment: Just found what looks to be answer https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4c397c2a-6570-477a-8f5e-2be43f6746eb/configure-ssrs-email-settings-smtp-server-with-port-number?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: thank you @AlanSchofield.  that fixed it, woo-hoo!  Adding the port# 587 in the reportserver config file.